# Mongo Import csv - How can import csv data starting from `x` row number into mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: windows, mongodb, csv

I have a `csv` file whose data I want to import into my `mongodb` but I want to make it point to a specific row number from were it should start importing the data from `csv` file.

Right now I'm importing it in the following way:

```
mongoimport -d dbname -c collection_name --type csv --file filename.csv --headerline
```

The reason I want to import it from a specific row number is because starting few rows are informational but not required to insert into DB.

```
SampleFile(2015),,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
Theme,Category,Topic
Automobile,Auto Brands,Acura
Automobile,Auto Brands,Aston Martin
```

So I want to point it from the row `Theme,Category,Topic`. Is it possible or do I have to manually edit the `csv` file for this.

Answer (score 2):

On unix or with a ported version you can use [`tail`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) to skip the lines in the file, as `mongoimport` will accept `STDIN` as an alternate to `--file`. You probably want to set up [`--fieldFile`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--fieldFile) for the headers as well since the `--headerline` cannot be used when you are not reading that first line in the file:

```
tail -n+<linesToSkip> | mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --type csv --headerfile headers.txt
```

Note the `+` there as that tells tail to "skip to that line"

If you don't want to install anything else on windows then use `for`:

```
for /f "skip=<linesToSkip> delims=\n" %i in (base.js) do @echo %i | | mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionname --type csv --headerfile headers.txt
```

In your sample though just skip the lines to the headerline and still use the option.

So just pipe the input to `STDIN` and allow `mongoimport` to slurp it up.

Comment: Thanks but `tail` is not helping me right now because I'm using `windows` as OS.

Comment: @TanveerAlam Google is your friend :) http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/ and http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: @TanveerAlam You might also want to look at the native windows shell way of doing it I added if you don't want to install a port of tail.

Comment: `@Blakes Seven` Thanks it did helped. I was expecting that mongoimport might have some extra argument to point row number.

Comment: @TanveerAlam No extra options, otherwise it would be documented. The answer always was essentially to "pipe" the content from another filter.

Comment: Yeah that is what my concern was because it is common use case while importing any csv file.

Comment: Just one more question is it possible to import two csv file and assign reference to one of each key field as objectId while importing it.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I think you need to consider here that a "design philophy" is "why do something another tool already does?". `mongoimport` itself is just a utility and not the only way to do it, there are language API's that let you build your own custom versions of whatever, including imports. On the other note if you have other questions then feel free to post them as other questions on stackoverflow. It's better that way where you can clearly word your question for people to answer. And "one" answer per question.

Comment: `@Blakes Seven` Thanks. Above explanation was helpful.